# FitNesse: How to send tests execution reports from Jenkins to an endpoint in JSON format?

Tags: json, jenkins, fitnesse

I have a task to send reports of periodic execution of FitNesse tests to some specific endpoint in some specific JSON format.

I set periodic execution of tests in Jenkins properties and saving it in XML, but now I need to parse information about results of it.

It cannot be just step in "after build" property in Jenkins (or can, but I don't know a plugin for it), but what it would be and how I can do this?

Especially, I don't need information about the test, only general moments like date of the test, pass rate, status, name of the project, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to solve this is to make a script that parses the XML file, and creates the required JSON file. We normally use python scripts for this.

If you need certain generic information of the build in the script, like build number, you can pass this to your script using the Jenkins environments.

To call the script just add a batch or shell step, and place it below your fitnesse build step, to make sure the XML is generated before calling the script.

Answer (score 0):

FitNesse comes with a jUnit runner which allows you to execute a test/suite. If you create a test class annotated with `@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)` and include its execution in a Jenkins Maven job (where the jUnit class is executed by either surefire or failsafe plugin), the outcome of the tests executed will be picked up automatically by Jenkins, just like it picks up other/regular jUnit tests (as surefire or failsafe will include them in their XML reports and Jenkins will pick these up).

You can find a sample Maven FitNesse project using (a slightly customised version of) this approach at https://github.com/fhoeben/sample-fitnesse-project. How to run the tests on Jenkins is described at https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures#to-run-the-tests-on-a-build-server:

> Have the build server checkout the project and execute `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test`. The result in JUnit XML results can be found in: `target/failsafe-reports` (Jenkins will pick these up automatically for a Maven job)

You indicate you don't need the HTML results, but they will be made available. They can be found in: `target/fitnesse-results/index.html`, and you could choose to use the 'HTML Publisher' Jenkins plugin to link to them from each build.

Comment: Thank you for advice. As I understood from your links, this approach helps to save results in xml-file and send them somewhere. But I already have the results in xml-fromat and can see summary of it in Jenkins page (like date of execution, amount of passed tests, etc.). And now my task is -- create JSON-file with specific scheme from this information and send it to some specific endpoint.

If I uncorrectrly understood you -- sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Maybe you can create a junit listener that creates the report in the right format and sends it.